# getting an error of "Service not found" in a async_resolve handler

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have code that looks like the following:

```
//unrelated code snipped
resolver.reset(new tcp::resolver(iosvc));
tcp::resolver::query query(host, port);
resolver->async_resolve(query,
    boost::bind(&TCPTransport::handle_resolve, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));

LOG4CXX_INFO(logger, "Attempting connection to at " << host << ":" << port);
//unrelated code snipped



void TCPTransport::handle_resolve(const boost::system::error_code& err,
  tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
{
  if (err)
  {
    LOG4CXX_ERROR(logger, "Error: " << err.message());
  }
  else
  {
    tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
    if (!socket)
    {
      socket.reset(new tcp::socket(iosvc));
    }
    socket->async_connect(endpoint,
      boost::bind(&TCPTransport::handle_connect, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++endpoint_iterator));
  }
}
```

When I run this code, with the appropriate gate and port of the server I know is up an running, I get the following text in my log file: Error: Service not found

Can anyone provide some insight into what this error actually means?

Comment: What's the type and contents of "port"? What version of Boost are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Boost it looks like that error can only happen as a result of a call to getaddrinfo().  [In MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520(VS.85).aspx) (for what it's worth), it sounds like the service name (or port) isn't supported for the types of socket that the caller (ASIO?) supports.

In other words, it *seems* like you're attempting a TCP connection on either a non-TCP socket (not likely, since you're using TCP classes for your DNS resolution) or to a non-TCP port (not sure what to do about that).

I recommend stepping into the code using a debugger to see what is going wrong, though that will be a lot easier if you use a synchronous call to resolve().  Otherwise you'll have to set multiple breakpoints on the various internal handlers that ASIO uses (not that bad, but still a nuisance).  Hope that helps...